# "Stretching" a 2D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I need to "stretch" a 2D Array filled with chars of ' ', and '*'.
The stretching is based on a "Int Factor" passed in through the method.

Current Image looks like this:

```
*****  
*      
*    * 
***    
*   *  
*     *
*****
```

Need it to look like this: (Assuming its Factor 2)

```
**********  
**      
**    ** 
******    
**   **  
**     **
**********
```

I started to write the loop for it but I have no idea if I'm on the right track or not, really struggling with this one.

EDIT: I've gotten the array col length to stretch, I need to get the image to stretch with it now.

```
 public void stretch ( int factor )
 {

factor = 2;
char[][] pixelStretch = new char[pixels.length][pixels[0].length * factor];
for (int row = 0; row < pixels.length; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < pixels[0].length; col+= factor) {

        for(int i=0; i<factor; i++) {
            pixelStretch[row][col+i] = pixels[row][col];
        }

}
}

pixels = pixelStretch;



}
```

Image printed from this:

```
**** 

   **
** 


****
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting "factor"? Then you wouldn't need it as an argument to the function.

Comment: Didnt realize I had that in there, thanks!

Comment: Do you only need to print the result?

Comment: Yes, I've made some progress. Ive actually gotten the 2D array to stretch. Now I just need to get the '*'s and ' ' to stretch with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  All you have to do, is change the code so that you're copying `pixels[row][column]` to the new array `factor` times

```
// make sure factor is not 0 before you do this
for (int col = 0; col < pixels[0].length; col++) {
   for(int i=0; i<factor; i++) {
       pixelStretch[row][col*factor+i] = pixels[row][col];
   }
}
```

Comment: Adding this in prints out an image that is quite interesting haha, it did not work :/

Comment: @user3344880 what did the image look like?

Comment: I've edited the main question with updated code/image!

Comment: @user3344880  you still have an extra `pixelStretch[row][col] = pixels[row][col];` after your for loop.  you're just writing the original array on top of the new array again

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and removed it. Its oddly still giving me the same image.

Comment: @user3344880 I was trying to get the value from pixels[col] while at the same time using [col] to index the stretched array.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: It works! Now let me see if I understand this correctly. This multiplies whats IN col by the factor... What does having the +i do?

Comment: @user3344880 if you didn't have the +i, it would write the same dot in the same space `factor` times.   It would look like only the spaces are stretched.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for the help my friend! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some problems with your loop:

for (int col = 0; col < pixels[0].length * factor; col--)

Here, you should use pixels[row].length to get the correction column. Furthermore, it should be col++ instead of col--

If you only need to print the result, you don't actually need to stretch the array.

```
public void stretch ( int factor )
    {
    for (int row = 0; row < pixels.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < pixels[row].length; col++) {
            char c = pixels[row][col];
            if (c == ' ')
                System.out.print(c);
            else
                for (int count = 0; count < factor; count++)
                    System.out.print(c);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This prints the star/asterisk 'factor' times, and the spaces only as often as they occur in the original.

Comment: The image is printed in another method                              `picture = new Image ( );
  picture.stretch (  3  );
  System.out.println ( "After streching, the picture is: " + picture  );`